# Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'url'

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a bibliography in BibDesk, and use biblatex with biber backend. However, biblatex complains `Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'url'.` and apparently falls back `Using fallback driver on input line 126.`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % rec'd by babel

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Url{nytnigeria2011,
    Author = {{New York Times}},
    Title = {Nigerians Vote in Presidential Election},
    Url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/world/africa/17nigeria.html},
    Urldate = {2012-03-25},
    Year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Dummytext~\cite{nytnigeria2011}.
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `@online` instead of `@Url` or `@article`

Comment: @egreg Make that an answer, please.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, I had another paper that didn't use `biber` as `biblatex` backend, which could be a reason that it worked, or I just never really paid any attention to the errors (I finished that at 5 in the morning).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `@url` entry type known to `biblatex`, but there's a `@online` one; you can choose also `@article`, if you know the precise data. This should work

```
@online{nytnigeria2011,
    Author = {{New York Times}},
    Title = {Nigerians Vote in Presidential Election},
    Url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/world/africa/17nigeria.html},
    Urldate = {2012-03-25},
    Year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: Aparently, BibDesk as of version 1.5.7 doesn't know about an `@online` field, however, it does have an `@electronic`, which according to the `biblatex` docs is a synonym for `@online`. Thanks and accepted :)

Comment: @Zsub I believe that BibDesk can be instructed to extend the accepted types.